# Map Leaflet, display multiple markers from a loop

Tags: javascript, twig

I would like to display markers whose latitude and longitude coordinates come from a database. I use a "for" loop to get the positions from the database. I am displaying my map using leaflet. I need help to know how I could display the markers. I have tried using the javascript function (getElementById) to get the values generated by the html code and use them but it does not work. I wonder if the solution would be to use another method, but I don't know.

Here is my code, the code is from a file in twig :

```
<body>
        <div id="mapwrap">
            <div id="toolbar">
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <span>Vos&nbsp;Robots</span>
                </div>
                <div id="tourstops">
                    <h2>Vos Robots</h2>
                    <div class="accordion sidebar-inner clearfix small-none">
                        {% for child in listPositionRobot %}
                            <h2 class=" accordion__items active" id="idbot"> Luna {{ child.getRobotName() }}</h2>
                            <div class="accordion__content open">
                                <ul class="accordion__content__caption flex flex-wrap space-between accordion-app">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Latitude : <p id="latbot">{{ child.getLatitude() }}</p></li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Longitude : <p id="lonbot">{{ child.getLongitude() }}</p></li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-hourglass-half"></i> Heure de la dernière communication : </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-terminal"></i> Dernier Ordre : </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> Heure : {{ child.getStringDate() }}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#toolbar .hamburger').on('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
            });

            $(function () {
                var links = $(".accordion__items");

                links.on('click', function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                        $(this).next().removeClass("open");
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
                        $(this).next().siblings().removeClass("open");
                        $(this).toggleClass("active");
                        $(this).next().toggleClass("open");
                    }
                });
            });

            var lat = 43.6961;
            var lon = 7.27178;
            var map = null;

            function initMap() {
                map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 15);
                L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: 'données © <a href="//osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>/ODbL - rendu <a href="//openstreetmap.fr">OSM France</a>',
                    minZoom: 1,
                    maxZoom: 20
                }).addTo(map);
                
                //var locationsLayers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

                var idRobot = document.getElementById('idbot').innerHTML;
                var thisLat = document.getElementById('latbot').innerHTML;
                var thisLon = document.getElementById('lonbot').innerHTML;

                var positionRobots = ["idRobot", thisLat, thisLon];

                for (var i = 0; i < positionRobots.length; i++) {
                    marker = new L.marker([positionRobots[i][1], positionRobots[i][2]])
                    .bindPopup(positionRobots[i][0])
                    .addTo(map);

                    $idRobot.on('click', function() {
                        map.panTo([thisLat,thisLon]);
                        //thisLayer.addTo(map);
                        locationsLayers.addLayer(thisLayer);
                        var notifyIcon = L.divIcon({
                            className: 'notify-icon',
                            iconSize: [25, 25],
                            html: '<span></span>'
                        });
                        var notifyMarker = L.marker([thisLat,thisLon], {icon: notifyIcon});
                        locationsLayers.addLayer(notifyMarker);
                        if(map.getSize().x < 768) {
                            $('#toolbar').removeClass('open');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                initMap();
            };
            function init() {
                init.called = true;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
```

I hope I have made it clear how I expressed myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `twig` variable directly in `JS`. In this case I would recommend to use `data-` attributes.

```
<div class="accordion__content open" data-lat="{{ child.getLatitude() }}" data-lon="{{ child.getLongitude() }}">
```

Then you can fetch the lats/longs in `JS` like

```
$('div[data-lat]').each(function() {
    marker = new L.marker($(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lon'))
                  .addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I did what you said but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I consulted the symfony documentation as well and found the same instruction as you but when I apply this, it still doesn't work.